# Hello, i'm working on a question response system and my problem is that each time I want to answer any question it always retrieves the last question

Tags: laravel, while-loop, eloquent

My ResponesController.php

```
     public function create()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('respone_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $categories = Category::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('Sélectionnez la thématique'), '');

        $author_emails = User::all()->pluck('email', 'id')->prepend(trans('Choisissez votre email'), '');

        $ask_questions = AskQuestion::all();
        $ask_questions = AskQuestion::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1)->get();

        return view('admin.respones.create', compact('categories', 'author_emails', 'ask_questions'));
    }

create.blade.php

    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('ask_question') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="required" for="ask_question_id"><strong>{{ trans('La question est:') }}</strong></label>

                                @foreach($ask_questions as $id => $ask_question)
                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" readonly="true" name="ask_question_id" id="ask_question_id"
                                    value="{{ $ask_question->id }}">
                                    <p>{{ $ask_question->text_question }}</p>
                                @endforeach

                                @if($errors->has('ask_question_id'))
                                    <span class="help-block" role="alert">{{ $errors->first('ask_question_id') }}</span>
                                @endif

                                <span class="help-block">
                                    {{ trans('') }}
                                </span>
                        </div>
```

In this blade before responding i retrieve the asked question at first but like i say at last it retrieve the last entry question
For example I have 100 questions I cannot answer 99 questions I can only answer 100th question. Please i need help

Answer (score 0):

You owerwriting $ask_questions. First you are taking all questions then owerwriting it with last one.

Comment: yes I want to change it and make sure to retrieve each question and answer it

Comment: you are owerwriting that your all questions and passing only one question (last) to yout blade. You have to use different variable for all questions and last one. U cannot owerwrite. It's just not right.

Comment: as i understand from your blade code that you want to show all awailable questions for user. is that right ? if so you just have to remove `$ask_questions = AskQuestion::orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1)->get();` this line from your code

Comment: No, it's not what I want. I just want to show a question and answer it but in this case I get the last (desc) or the first (asc) with this: $ ask_questions = AskQuestion :: orderBy ('id', 'desc') -> limit (1 ) -> get (); and even if I take it off the result stays the same

Comment: which question do you want to show ? do you want to answer your questions one by one ? i don't understand your problem quite well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209380/discussion-between-jp-and-ramnas-pabrza).

Comment: ah. So your logic has to be different. There is many ways to do it. One for example is to get all not answered questions by user. If you are saving your answers you have to set user_id and question_id for that answer. so before showing next question you have to get all answeres question IDs and filter questions e.g. AskQuestion::whereNotIn('id', [1,2,3,4,5,6])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1)->get();

Comment: Great now you're on right way to help me... let me try it but if you have any suggest it's welcome